# Some property of conditional independence

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

Given random variables $Y, Z, X_1, X_2$

Is there some relation between

- $Y $ and $Z$ are conditionally independent given $(X_1, X_2)$
- $Y $ and $Z$ are conditionally independent given $X_1$, and given $X_2$

My guess is that the former implies the latter, but not vice versa, since the sigma algebras generated by the random variables $\sigma(X_1),\sigma(X_2) \subseteq \sigma(X_1, X_2)$?

When will they become equivalent?

Is there some reference which state properties of conditional independence? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Let  $Y$, $X_1$ and $X_2$ be independent random variables with uniform distribution on $[0,1]$.

Now let $$Z=X_1+X_2+Y\mod 1.$$

Then the random variables $Z$ and $Y$ are independent conditionally on $X_1$ and conditionally on $X_2$ but clearly not conditional on $X_1$ and $X_2$. So the second condition does not imply the first one.

Comment: Thanks! Do you think the first imply the second?

Comment: @Tim I have o think some more about it.

Answer (score 0):

The first condition does not imply the second one. Take a constant random variable $X_1$. Then the conditional independence between $Y$ and $Z$ given $(X_1,X_2)$ is the conditional independence between $Y$ and $Z$ given $X_2$, and the conditional independence between $Y$ and $Z$ given $X_1$ is the independence between $Y$ and $Z$. It is possible that $Y$ and $Z$ are conditionally independent given $X_2$, but not independent.